# return array of modified objects selected by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects for table rows:

```
let data = [{name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me'},
{name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me'},
{name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me'}]
```

and meta for columns

```
const columns = [
    {
      id: 'name',
      accessor: 'name',
      label: 'file name',
      numeric: false,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      id: 'date',
      label: 'created (date)',
      accessor: 'date',
      modifier: value => {
        let date = new Date(value);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let monthIndex = date.getMonth();
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let hour = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();
        return `${day}.${monthIndex}.${year} ${hour}:${
          minutes.toString().length <= 1 ? '0' + minutes : minutes
        }`;
      },
      numeric: false,
      sortable: true
    }
```

I need function generateTableRows(data, columns) returns new array of modified objects. Each object contains only keys and its values from columns meta and if modifier is used override default value with that returned from callback.

```
const result = 
[{name: 'some', date: modifier(value)},
{name: 'some', date: modifier(value)},
{name: 'some', date: modifier(value)}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the question? And where is code for `generateTableRows()`

Comment: What's your question? (Hint: a question ends in a question mark =>?)

Comment: You know I tried many combination of data.map within columns.map it was so messy that I deleted all code and lost motivation to undestand at least logic. That was just stackoverflow  in my head that just need help with somehow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the needed modifiers and map the objects with new properties.

```js
var columns = [{ id: 'name', accessor: 'name', label: 'file name', numeric: false, sortable: true }, { id: 'date', label: 'created (date)', accessor: 'date', modifier: value => { let date = new Date(value); let day = date.getDate(); let monthIndex = date.getMonth(); let year = date.getFullYear(); let hour = date.getHours(); let minutes = date.getMinutes(); return `${day}.${monthIndex}.${year} ${hour}:${minutes.toString().length <= 1 ? '0' + minutes : minutes}`; }, numeric: false, sortable: true }],
    data = [{ name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me' }, { name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me' }, { name: 'some', date: 1553187727592, user: 'me' }],
    modifiers = columns.reduce((m, { id, modifier }) => m.set(id, modifier), new Map),
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: (modifiers.get(k) || (v => v))(v) }))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you use any online tool or code editor to format it this way or just click on *Tidy* in stack snippet and do some changes?

Comment: @adiga, sometime i write the formatting by hand, sometimes with visual studio with a later custom formatting in an other editor.